# How can I trigger reopening of Jira Service Management tickets 6 months after creation for audit?

Tags: automation, jira, service-management

Reopen a Jira Service Management ticket 6 months after it was created.

We have a business flow requiring an audit (review) of tickets at both 6 months and a year after the ticket was initially created.

I've adjusted the workflows for these specific business cases to allow for the tickets to be reopened with custom statuses for each audit and created some automation based on the conditions for the tickets. My issue is I can't figure out the trigger. I initially thought about using transition to closed but checking the create date for 6 months or a year prior will never trigger what I need. I've also thought about moving the entire project to Work Management instead of Service Management.

Ultimately, I need these tickets to reopen for Audit 6 months after the create date, and again at 12 months after the create date.